# WooCommerce Subscriptions plugin: not compatible with PayPal standard?

Tags: woocommerce, subscriptions

Recently installed WooCommerce Subscriptions plugin. I get this message on checkout page: "Sorry, it seems there are no available payment methods which support subscriptions" although I have PayPal standard enabled & configured ([the doc says](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/subscriptions/payment-gateways/) PayPal standard is compatible with the plugin)

Any idea why I get that error?

Comment: This is a question for Woo support.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed it would be slow but I'll try anyway :)

Comment: I'm sure it will be. From what I know, they're struggling to keep up with their support queue. It's just that this isn't a programming question so is off-topic here.

Answer (score -1):

Go to `Woocommerce > Settings > Subscriptions (tab) > Renewals (section) >` and check  Accept Manual Renewals. Your payments should work.